# How to effectively clean all the format of a range of cells in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sure it must be a silly mistake I'm doing, but I'm trying to read the last column number of the row number 4 of my Excel file using VBA and then use this value as a parameter to clean the formatting of all cells up to that column, but all I get is the is the run-time error '424' object required.

Using the debugging tool I can see the lastRow and lastColumn variables are set correctly, but this part of the code seems to hang:

[image]

The full code is here:

```
Function cleanUp()

Dim dateRow As Integer
Dim weekNumber As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lasColumn As Long

' Initialize dateRow
dateRow = 4

' Works in the Launches worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2023")
    
' Find the limits (row and column)
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
lastColumn = ws.Cells(dateRow, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

' Clean the today's date cell formating
For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Cells(dateRow, 10), ws.Cells(dateRow, lastColumn))
    If cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
        ws.Cells(dateRow, cell.Column).Interior.ColorIndex = x1none
        ws.Cells(dateRow, cell.Column).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        ws.Cells(dateRow, cell.Column).Font.Bold = False
        Exit For
    End If
Next cell

' Clean the data formating
For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
    ws.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column).Interior.ColorIndex.x1none
Next cell
End Function
```

Comment: `x1none` ----> `xlNone`. `ws.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column).Interior.ColorIndex.x1none` ----> `ws.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone`.

Comment: If you had `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, it would have flagged the first instance of `x1none`.

Comment: Hi @BigBen, changing from "x1none"'  to "x1None" didn't help.

Comment: Get rid of the loop: `For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))` and just use `ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone`.

Comment: It's not a "1" (one), it's a "L" (letter). **Use Option Explicit**

Comment: Hi @BigBen, I removed the loop and changed the "1" to "l" as you suggested and now everything is working as it should, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help from @BigBen and @FunThomas, I solved the issue.

I removed the loop in that part of the code and made sure to use "L" instead of "1". So the final code is:

```
' Clean the data formating
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
```

For reference, the original part of the code was:

```
' Clean the data formating
For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
    ws.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column).Interior.ColorIndex.x1none
Next cell
```

It is working fine now.